# Can I configure record identification to work with custom naming and a custom controller for a rails resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, url-routing, form-generator

Suppose I have defined in my routes the following line

```
resources :a, controller: 'b', as: 'a'
```

and the following controller

```
class BController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def new
    @b = B.new
  end

  def edit
    @b = B.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Is there a way to write a form partial so that I can use it on both the new and edit views? For example, if I write

```
<%= form_for @b do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Rails gives me a routing error.

---

### Inelegant Solution

I came up with an inelegant solution to write the BController as

```
class BController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def new
    @b = B.new
    @url = bs_path
  end

  def edit
    @b = B.find(params[:id])
    @url = b_path
  end
end
```

and then write the form as

```
<%= form_for(@b, url: @url) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

I wonder if there is a more "Rails" way to accomplish this though without having to write in the @url variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you might be looking for the `:path` option to the [resources](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources)...if I followed your example correctly, you have a model `B` and you want to access it at `/a` or `/a/:id` and be able to use `a_path(instance_of_b)`...so I feel like you want your route to be

```
resources :b, as: 'a', path: 'a'
```

and I believe that'll do what you're wanting.

Comment: Thanks for the API reference!